# Are new_or_get and get_or_create the same?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, get

Here is my code.

**views.py**

```
cart_obj, cart_created = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
```

**models.py**

```
def new_or_get(self, request):
        cart_id = request.session.get("cart_id", None)
        qs = self.get_queryset().filter(id=cart_id)
        if qs.count() == 1:
            new_obj = False
            cart_obj = qs.first()
            if request.user.is_authenticated() and cart_obj.user is None:
                cart_obj.user = request.user
                cart_obj.save()
        else:
            cart_obj = Cart.objects.new(user=request.user)
            new_obj = True
            request.session['cart_id'] = cart_obj.id
        return cart_obj, new_obj
```

I wanted to understand what `cart_obj, cart_created` meant. I Googled it and found the below.

- Any keyword arguments passed to `get_or_create()` — except an optional
  one called defaults — will be used in a `get()` call. If an object is
  found, `get_or_create()` returns a tuple of that object and False. If
  multiple objects are found, `get_or_create` raises
  MultipleObjectsReturned. If an object is not found, `get_or_create()`
  will instantiate and save a new object, returning a tuple of the new
  object and True. The new object will be created roughly according to
  this algorithm:

I thought the above description described what was happening in my code (or at least described something quite similar to what my code was doing). But in my code I use `new_or_get` whereas the above description relates to `get_or_create`.

I added two print statements to my code so I could get better understand it.

```
cart_obj, cart_created = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
print("cart created")
print(cart_created)
```

In my code `cart_created` appeared to be a boolean value (which was mentioned in the above description relating to `get_or_create`).

So my question is, are `get_or_create` and `new_or_get` the same? If they are not the same, what are the differences? I found documentation relating to `get_or_create` but not `new_or_get`.

**Update**

I failed to appreciate the value from `(1)cart_obj` would be passed to `(a)cart_obj` and that the value from `(2)new_obj` would be passed to `(b)cart_created`. To clarify in my code I don't have actual have '(1)(2)(a)(b)', it was done for comment sake because I used `cart_obj` in views.py and models.py.

I failed to appreciate that `cart_obj`, `cart_created` and `new_obj` were all just arbitrary names.

```
(a)cart_obj, (b)cart_created =

return (1)cart_obj, (2)new_obj
```

I only discovered they were arbitrary names when I changed the code to the below and it still worked.

```
return cart_obj, new_objtest
```

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I will be surprised if you can find documentation on `new_or_get` because it's a custom-made function.

What the new_or_get method does is that, if there is only 1 object in the `cart_id` queryset, you don't create a new object; you get the first object in the queryset - which should be a cart - and save it if the current user is logged in. Otherwise, you create a new cart. `Cart_obj` is the received/created cart object and `new_obj` is a boolean regarding if a new cart is created or not.

This is pretty similar to the standard `get_or_create` method. The difference is that `get_or_create` only returns the object when found but your `new_or_get` handles objects more elaborately as it *involves authentication and sessions* -- what `get_or_create` doesn't come with. Otherwise, the two returned objects are pretty much equivalent.

Comment: Thank you for the help, after reading your comment I reevaluated my code and had a brain wave.